# Auth::attempt() not working - Laravel 4

Tags: php, sql, laravel

I've seen through all other questions but I can't figure why My Auth::attempt is not working

Then, I'll display the code involved on it:

-- models/Usuario.php --

```
use \Illuminate\Auth\UserInterface;

class Usuario extends Eloquent implements UserInterface{

    protected $table = 'User_Account';
    protected $hidden = array('password');

    public function getAuthIdentifier() {
            return $this->getKey();
    }
    public function getAuthPassword() {
            return $this->password;
    }
}

?>
```

auth.php

```
<?php

return array(

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Default Authentication Driver
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This option controls the authentication driver that will be utilized.
    | This driver manages the retrieval and authentication of the users
    | attempting to get access to protected areas of your application.
    |
    | Supported: "database", "eloquent"
    |
    */

    'driver' => 'eloquent',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Authentication Model
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | When using the "Eloquent" authentication driver, we need to know which
    | Eloquent model should be used to retrieve your users. Of course, it
    | is often just the "User" model but you may use whatever you like.
    |
    */

    'model' => 'Usuario',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Authentication Table
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | When using the "Database" authentication driver, we need to know which
    | table should be used to retrieve your users. We have chosen a basic
    | default value but you may easily change it to any table you like.
    |
    */

    'table' => 'User_Account',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Password Reminder Settings
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may set the settings for password reminders, including a view
    | that should be used as your password reminder e-mail. You will also
    | be able to set the name of the table that holds the reset tokens.
    |
    | The "expire" time is the number of minutes that the reminder should be
    | considered valid. This security feature keeps tokens short-lived so
    | they have less time to be guessed. You may change this as needed.
    |
    */

    'reminder' => array(

        'email' => 'emails.auth.reminder',

        'table' => 'password_reminders',

        'expire' => 60,

    ),

);
```

My Route::post(Controller@method) here:
    $validator = $this->getLoginValidator();

```
        if ($validator->passes()) {
            if(Auth::attempt(array('username' => Input::get('username'), 'password' => Input::get('password')))){
                   echo "entrou";
            }
              echo "n entrou";
        } else{
            echo "Validation failed!";
        }
```

I've seen what comes from each Input::get and everything seems alright.
Just to information, my tables like this:
 Column Type    Null    Default Comments
id  int(8)  No
firstname   varchar(40) No
lastname    varchar(40) No
password    varchar(60) No
username    varchar(40) No
points  int(8)  No  0
created_at  datetime    No
updated_at  datetime    No

If you need additional information in order to help me, I'd freely give.

Comment: What does the code output? What does your view look like?

Comment: Shouldn't the password field be 64 characters?

Comment: @John , the view shows the "error" message from PHP. (something went wrong).

Comment: @Kousha, I've changed to 64 and nothing happened

Comment: @EduardoStuart , obrigado, to lendo ele agora. Consegui achar que meu Validator precisa que meu Model implemente UserInterface, to testando agora.

Comment: @EduardoStuart, pelo meu log, eu achei, por conta que o Auth precisa de alguns métodos abstratos sejam implementados.

Comment: @EduardoStuart and FelipeBormann, please type in English so others can follow you as well.